# Verilator, running simulator gives: Invalid argument

Tags: verilog, simulation, verilator

I'm following [this](https://zipcpu.com/tutorial/lsn-01-wires.pdf) tutorial. On page 24 I don't get the Makefile the tutorial talks about. When I run `./thruwire` it says: `bash: ./thruwire: Invalid argument`.

This is my thruwire.v:

```
module thruwire(i_sw, o_led);
    input   wire    i_sw;
    output  wire    o_led;
    
    assign o_led = i_sw;
endmodule
```

After having generated this verilog file I ran these commands to create the obj_dir directory:

```
verilator -Wall -cc thruwire.v
cd obj_dir
make -f Vthruwire.mk
```

I then created a file thruwire.cpp in my main directory (so the one above obj_dir) that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Vthruwire.h"
#include "verilated.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Verilated::commandArgs(argc, argv);
    
    Vthruwire *tb = new Vthruwire;
    
    for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
    {
        tb->i_sw = k&1;
        
        tb->eval();
        
        printf("k = %2d, ", k);
        printf("i_sw = %2d, ", tb->i_sw);
        printf("led = %2d, ", tb->o_led);
    }
}
```

I went back one directory and compiled everything like this:

```
cd ..
g++ -I /usr/share/verilator/include -I obj_dir /usr/share/verilator/include/verilated.cpp thruwire.cpp obj_dir/Vthruwire__ALL.a -o thruwire
```

By now, I've done everything that the tutorial says up till slide 24. However, there is no Makefile in my project directory, as should be the case according to the tutorial. When I run ./thruwire I get said error.

I'm new to all this, please help me out. Am I missing something?

I tried using the --exe flag, since [the documentation](https://veripool.org/guide/latest/verilating.html#c-and-systemc-generation) says a simulation executable will be generated for me. But it gives me the same error upon running. I tried specifying arguments myself and removing the arguments from the main function alltogether but it keeps giving me that error.

I'm running the simulation in a virtual box image. I recently shrunk the .vdi using [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/312883/how-to-shrink-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-and-free-up-disk-space/) guide. I don't know if that could have anything to do with it.

Comment: I'm just gonna reinstall my virtual machine I guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My toolbox was broken. A working toolbox does not give these errors as has been discussed in the comments (unfortunately the user deleted them). I guess trying to build the whole toolsuite yourself is not a good idea unless you really know what you are doing. I found a [cad suite](https://github.com/YosysHQ/oss-cad-suite-build) that can be readily used without problems. It has all the needed tools precompiled and working.

Comment: this does not answer your question, you better move it to a comment.

Comment: My question was am I missing something, and yes, I was missing something: a completely prebuilt tool suite. Also, the error was being caused by a broken toolbox which is the answer to why it wasn't working.